# Изменить цвет текста при наложении на фон

Tags: css

Есть такой код:

```css
.col {
  margin-left: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.text {
font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s6 offset-s6 bg_black"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="text">
        Я большой кусок текста
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Текст черный на белом фоне, а вот правая часть страницы залита темным фоном. В зависимости от размера экрана часть текста находится над фоном. Как именно эту часть текста можно сделать белой? Пробовал mix-blend-mode, серый в разных оттенках, а вот сделать текст белым никак.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.col {
  margin-left: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.row {
  background:linear-gradient(to left, black 30%, white 30%);      
}
.text {
font-size: 40px;
mix-blend-mode:difference;
  color:white;
  padding-left: 180px
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s6 offset-s6 bg_black"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="text">
        Я большой кусок текста
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```