# Как сделать подобный эффект с css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать подобный эффект с текстом, чтобы он был другого цвета, когда налазил на картинку? Буду благодарен за помощь)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Изменить цвет текста при наложении на фон](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1017879/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd)

Comment: [другой дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1091454/178576). и куда только смотрят местные знатоки css? может быть, не ищут дубликаты потому, что лень, а может быть потому, что у вопросов (как и у данного) очень плохая формулировка?

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.parent {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, black 40%, transparent 40%);
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  margin: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 300%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, white 40%, black 40%);
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще вариант. Он позволяет поиграть не только c текстом.

```css
.content {
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 20px;  
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  backdrop-filter: invert() grayscale();
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<img src="https://www.thehappycatsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Black-and-White-Cat-Names-HC-long.jpg" alt="cat" width="200" height="108">
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: А как быть с ff, кроме как в about:config лезть?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov зависит от того, насколько критичен элемент. В примере ничего не сломается в FF в плане доступности контента.  Usage 90% норм, чтобы поиграться.

Comment: в плане требуемого эффекта ваш вариант не работает в ff (97.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

Одной из идей является дублирование текста

```
<h1 class="lp-header first">Наша команда</h1>
<h1 class="lp-header second">Наша команда</h1>
```

Переменные CSS используются для определения цвета, благодаря этому можно легко изменить их в одном месте, если понадобится цвет отличный от чёрно белого.
Также использован `clip-path`, чтобы скрыть половину одного текста и показать другую:

***Для смены цвета текста и фона,- наведите курсор***

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  --c1:white;
  --c2:black;
}
body:hover {
  --c1:crimson;
  --c2:blue;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family:Verdana;
  margin: 0;
}
.first {
  background:var(--c1);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px var(--c2);
}

.second {
  background:var(--c2);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px var(--c1);
  clip-path:polygon(0% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 100%,0% 100%);
}

.lp-header {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  min-height:100vh;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  transition:0.5s;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="lp-header first">Наша команда</h1>
<h1 class="lp-header second">Наша команда</h1>
```